# How to Change a Tab's content page dynamically?

Tags: angular, ionic3

Here is reproduction code of the problem on StackBlitz, feel free to adjust as needed.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-yjlfhv?file=app%2FTabsPage.ts

The expected behavior is that the OptionPage broadcasts a Changed event then the TabsPage reacts and sets a different rootPage for the “View” tab. This should get reflected when the tab is selected programmatically or by the user.

Even if the TabsPage.ts code does not programmatically select the View tab, the View tab is still requiring an explicit user click to update.

How can we fix this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iteration
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-shrsj2

in `OptionsPage.html`

```
<span *ngFor="let page of pages; index as i" >
   <button ion-button
      (click)="ViewSet(i)">
      Broadcast OptionsChanged to View{{i+1}}
    </button>
</span>
```

in `OptionsPage.ts`

```
  pages = [
    View1Page,
    View2Page
  ];

  constructor(
    public ViewService: ViewService
  ) {
    this.ViewSet(0);
  }

  ViewSet(i) {
    this.ViewService.OptionChanged.next(this.pages[i]);
  }
```

in `TabsPage.html`

```
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab [root]="optionPage" tabTitle="Options" tabIcon="settings"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tabPage" [tabTitle]="'View'" tabIcon="information-circle">
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>


optionPage = OptionsPage;
tabPage = ViewPages;
```

in `ViewPages.ts`

```
  constructor(
    public navController: NavController,
    public ViewService: ViewService
  ) {
  }

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.ViewService.OptionChanged.subscribe(data => {
      this.navController.setRoot(data);
    })
  }
```

Comment: @Meryan Let me know if this code works better for you than previous. ))

Comment: Thank you so much for putting time into this, I like much better your 2nd and 3rd (this answer) iterations.  I will probably have to accept it as a solution.  What is the significance of [tabTitle]="'View'" ? why not just tabTitle="View" which seems to work as well.  I feel dumb after 3+ years on/off of ionic/angular coding I still don't understand these nuances :( they made their framework an unnecessary pain as far as I am concerned, 70% of the time I fighting these stupid issues instead of working on my apps issues.

Comment: I am still toying around with this answer.  1) You have used an empty "dummy" default page ViewPages for the initial "View" tab.  2) You make this page listen for the broadcast and do a setRoot on the received page 3) you make the OptionsPage broadcast the actual page instance.  About the later would it be possible to make OptionsPage not know about the actual views? perhaps delegate it to a service?

Comment: Before seeing your last 2 iterations I was about to fall back on an approach I used in a different app, where I **stay away** from trying to change Tab assigned page since it's been such a pain.  Instead I make  ViewPages host several View-header components (VH1, VH2, VH3, ..) and likewise make its content host several View-content "child" components (VC1, VC2, VC3, ...) then I show and hide via [hidden] (or *ngIf) based on some global service flag.

Comment: Could you please peek at this variation on your answer https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ulv2yk?file=app%2FOptionsPage.ts 1) I moved knowledge/references to View1Page and View1Page to ViewService 2) Made app.comp.ts subscribe and perform the navigation, though ViewService would be a more intuitive place for me.  3) There is still a glitch as I am probably grabbing the wrong Navigation in app.component.ts, because when I click on the View tab the dummy page ViewPages appears.

Comment: My brain does not grasp this NavController thingy (although I have read and read on it in the past)  When you are doing .setRoot() the app stays in OptionsPage() which is good when the user is in this "Settings" page, however when I used .setRoot() it activates the View tab but with the flaw I described above. I do have a desired scenario for this auto selection behavior from a 3rd tab where the user makes a selection to a chapter and I want to auto navigate to the View tab.

Comment: @Meryan you can set selected tab `<ion-tabs [selectedIndex]="mySelectedIndex">`

Comment: [tabTitle]="tabName" you can dynamically change tab name ))

Comment: My experience with ionic-v3 6 month ))

Answer (score 0):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-tgcblm

You can try like this,

```
.View2Page

import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { NavController } from "ionic-angular";
import { View1Page } from "./View1Page";
import { ViewService } from "./ViewService";

@Component({
   selector: "View2Page",
   templateUrl: "View2Page.html"
})

export class View2Page {

constructor(
   public navController: NavController,
   public ViewService: ViewService
) {
}

ionViewDidEnter() {
   this.ViewService.OptionChanged.subscribe(data => {
      if (data === 'View1') {
         this.navController.setRoot(View1Page);
      }
   })
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into a solution, to simplify the post I showed only 2 views but I have many.  I have a concern about your code in that View1Page and View2Page have a mutual awareness. Is it possible to code your solution differently perhaps thru a service so that the View pages don't know about each other?  I am not sure how setRoot() will impact the navigation of the applciation, but I will live with that. Thank you.

Comment: I am having hard time even understand why your code works the way it does.  How is that View2Page listens (subscribes) to "View1" message to setRoot(View1Page) that' so **counter-intuitive** could you please explain the logic?.  Thank you.  (I have done a dozen iterations and attempts with NavParams, getActiveNav, getActiveNavs(), Tabs.select(), Content.resize() on ViewXPage(s) but sofar no success

Comment: Try this variant https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-78r15n?file=app/View1Page.ts